# How do I get an UNCONFIRMED account's AWSCognitoIdentityUser object?

Tags: iphone, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

In the AWSCognitoIdentityProvider iOS Swift library, to resend a verification code either by SMS or email, a user object is required and this is retrieved from calling a user pool's SignUp method. Once the SignUp method is successfully called, a user object, of type AWSCognitoIdentityUser, is returned. To resend a new verification code one of the following two methods can be called on that user object:

```
var pool: AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.init(forKey: 
    AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey)
}

...

AWSCognitoIdentityUser.getAttributeVerificationCode("email")  

// or

AWSCognitoIdentityUser.resendConfirmationCode()
```

However, after 24 hours, if a verification code isn't used to set an account in the "CONFIRMED" state, the verification code expires by default, and a new one is required for verification. If the user closes the iPhone app, there is no way I can find to retrieve the user's AWSCognitoIdentityUser object in order to resend another verification code to them. The user can't login to retrieve the user's object because UNCONFIRMED accounts can't sign in. Attempting to re-SignUp using the SignUp method fails because the account already exists.

**How do I get an UNCONFIRMED account AWSCognitoIdentityUser object in order to resend a new verification code?**

Comment: What is the exact question here? What the admin wants to do? If you highlight it I try to answer.

Comment: Updated the question and added a reference to the product’s official, relevant, issue documentation. There is a buried workaround from the issue discussion that isn’t explored in that open issue, yet, it is noted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been open since May 23, 2016, and appears to still be open. See this exact issue discussed at [aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js Issue #42](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/42) on github.

According to the issue discussion, above, a workaround may be not to use email aliases in the Cognito user pool, but instead require a username to avoid the alias issue which causes the wrong exception (user not found) to be returned and thus no signal that the account exists and is in the UNCONFIRMED state. I'm still not sure if this will enable a method to return the user account's AWSCognitoIdentityUser object used to resend a new verification code, but I will try this workaround and report back.

EDIT:

Found that you can use getSession for a specific user account. It's undocumented that it takes a password. You can use "deadbeef" as the password and it still gets that user's object. Once retrieved, a new verification code can be sent, even if the user is unconfirmed. Recomend doing this before calling sign-up to check to see if the user exists, if it's authorized to pull the user, if resources are available, if the user is unconfirmed (I automatically send another verification if this is the case because I use e-mail verification links), etc.